# Redis Failure Backup Simulation

Tags: redis, persistence

I'm using a redis server (v. 2.4.6) with RDB persistence enabled on a windows 8 machine. I want to simulate a redis failure and reset, so I can be more confident in my backup process.

I have found lots of information about redis persistence and backups, but I can't figure out what to do once a failure happens.

I've tried copying my dump.rdb with lots of test data from data folder, then uninstalling/reinstalling redis, pasting original dump.rdb file into new data folder and running. When I run the command "keys *", it says empty list or set.

So, how can I simulate a failure of the redis database and then restore it?

EDIT: I was overwriting the rdb file BEFORE I shutdown redis, causing overwrite. Now these are the steps I am taking to simulate a failure and backup.

1. I stop the redis service
2. I overwrite the dump.rdb file with the rdb file from a test database (on another server)
3. I try to start the redis service again, but I get the error "The Redis Server service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

If i delete the rdb file, I can start the service and it creates an empty rdb file in the same location.

This is what it shows in the redis.log file: "Can't handle RDB format version 6", but both of the databases use the exact same version of redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently my test database used a different version of redis (I thought they were the same). I got another rdb file from a test database that use v 2.4.6 as well and everything loaded up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `SNAPSHOTTING` part of your `redis.conf` file.
Your rdb dump filename and path are defined there (separate parameters).

Make sure you put your dump in the correct folder and with the correct name, the restore will happen when you start your Redis.

How about killing your Redis process to simulate failure?

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's essentially what I've been doing. I made some edits to my original question. Does the new info give you any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Go to redis-stable dir and run 
./src/redis-server

That worked for me.